# store non- mobile user Login tokens in clientData and fetch tokens whenever required in mobilefirst

Tags: mobilefirst-server

I Want to test MFP adapter 8.0 using Postman

Steps followed -

1. Registered the confidential client in MobileFirst Operations Console.
2. Using Postman, Obtained access token from MobileFirst Server token endpoint.

I am able to get access token using url - /mfp/api/az/v1/token

3. And used the access token received from MobileFirst Server token endpoint to make requests to the desired resources.

Now can I know how to store  Login tokens in clientData and fetch tokens whenever required  using -

clientData.getProtectedAttributes().get("");

Currently getting null pointer exception while getting clientId from clientData

```
String clientId = (String) clientData.getProtectedAttributes().get("clientId");
```

Update : Attached snapshot of Request parameter passed for Token step
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVhLV.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The observed behaviour is expected and by design.

A confidential client does not have a clientId and no associated clientData.Client Data is populated only when using mobile SDK to do registration and subsequent operations.

Comment: Is there any way so that non - mobile SDK can do registration and subsequent operations.

Comment: Check out https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/08/09/performance-testing-for-mobilefirst-foundation-8-0/

Comment: I am able to get response for preauthorize endpoint by passing client_id and scope
using url - /mfp/api/preauth/v1/preauthorize

 But I am not able to get response for authorization endpoint -

/mfp/api/az/v1/authorization?scope=LoginAuth&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://mfpredirecturi&client_id=00155391-cf41-4b97-89ae-87d7a1494910&isAjaxRequest=true

redirect_uri is failing.

Giving error - can’t connect to the server at mfpredirecturi .

Can I know how to solve this issue.

@Vivin K

Comment: Do not try to connect to redirect_uri. Follow the steps in the blog provided to proceed.

Comment: Token Step is failing. Url used  - /mfp/api/az/v1/token  .Response received is - {"errorCode":"invalid_client","errorMsg":"Incorrect JWT format"}. Attached the snapshot of Request parameter passed in question section. Can you please let me know how to solve this issue. @Vivin K

Comment: Happens if the registration details ( already in DB) and what you are sending does not match. Again, refer to the blog.

Comment: Its working now, Thank you @Vivin K